# NumberFormatter negative value to positive

Tags: ios, swift, numberformatter

I would like to convert a negative value into a positive one using `NumberFormatter`. The value should represent a percent change and should look like this: `1.46%` even if the value is negative `-1.46`.

There is a  `numberFormatter.negativeFormat`, but I am unsure what the format should look like. I tried `numberFormatter.negativeFormat = "0.00"` but the percent sign disappears and I do not want to add it explicitly at the end, because I am using `numberStyle`

```
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
```

Any ideas what would be the best solution?

Comment: Why not take the absolute value before handing it over to the formatter? It makes no sense to ask the _formatter_ to do it. It formats; it doesn't do _math_.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `Double` type to create a specific property that returns a `String` with the absolute value:

```
extension Double {
    var positivePercent: String {
        return abs(self).formatted(.percent)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let a = -0.0146
print(a.positivePercent)   // 1.46%
```

Comment: thanks, looks good, but only valid for iOS 15 and higher. Any ideas about a solution for versions below?

Comment: @Artiom this is basically the same solution as is suggested in the comments section so why not do as everyone suggests and take the absolute value of the number before formatting it?